# Is it haram to copy my friend's assignment and submit it?

Tags: halal-haram, school, cheating

I have an assignment to submit tomorrow and my friend has finished his. Can I copy his or will I have to do it myself? I had heard it is Haram to copy in Islam in papers. But what is the ruling on assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Passing off someone else's work as your own is considered deceitful since your teachers expect that the work is done by yourself and it is marked with the same understanding.

Comment: If the owner give it by its own wish?